# How to solve triadiagonal matrix using Numpy\Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, diagonal

I'm working on a project and i want to solve a system of tridiagonal matrix with9  equations with 9 unknowns in 20 steps. How do i go about the code using numpy\python.

Here is an example
 [Tridiagonal Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf95s.png)

I am solving for x11, x12, x13, x21, x22, x23, x31, x32, x33
I haven't tried any code at all. I just started learning python. If i can get the code for the matrix above, i can be able to bring up the code for the project i'm working on.

Comment: Hello, can you show us what you tried so that we can iterate on it ?

Comment: Such accuracy on the number of steps smells the homework or the quiz.

Comment: Hello Ben, I have edited and added an example to my question.

Comment: The matrix in the example is not tridiagonal.

Comment: I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: perform the forward sweep to eliminate the sub-diagonal;

Step 2: perform back substitution to eliminate the super-diagonal.

This is the Thomas algorithm.